# How to stop loading of iframes, when it is already loaded on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

I have multiple input textbox parameters in my web page and On 'Submit' of a button, there loads multiple iframes. On first time submit , the iframes are laoded properly. The problem is ,When it is already loaded , when i click the Submit button again , the iframes are reloaded and causes a blur in the browser.  How to stop loading of iframes, when it is already loaded on button click..
Mycode as

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBTNSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="lnkBTNSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="return validate();">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

My .cs code

```
protected void lnkBTNSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    SetReportsUrlsToIFrame(ObjSharedEntities.RequestID);
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "ScriptRegistration", "setVisibility('hide', 'inline');", true);
        }
```

Any suggestions ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your OnClick method

```
protected void lnkBTNSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ViewState["iframesDisplayed"] == null || !(bool)ViewState["iframesDisplayed"])
    {
        SetReportsUrlsToIFrame(ObjSharedEntities.RequestID);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "ScriptRegistration", "setVisibility('hide', 'inline');", true);
        ViewState["iframesDisplayed"] = true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to disabled the button when iframes have already loaded, then just set the button disabled.

```
protected void lnkBTNSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
SetReportsUrlsToIFrame(ObjSharedEntities.RequestID);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "ScriptRegistration", "setVisibility('hide', 'inline');", true);
lnkBTNSubmit.Enabled=false;
//or lnkBTNSubmit.Visible=false;
    }
```

but, if you need the button to work as usual, and no refresh(blur) occurs in your page, the answer is : NO WAY.
the reason is basic and simple, of course you know it, i put it here just to keep my answer complete.
when you click the submit button,  the html (aspx) page will post back to the server, and your browser becomes empty. when the server receives your postback, it will generate another newer page according to your request, and send the new page to your browser. when your browser receives the new page, it dispalys the new content.
in this process, content displayed in your browser changes as following: old page -> empty -> new page. so you see the blur and refresh.

Comment: Depending on what he wants to do, he could use AJAX and update panels.